# R: Removing all letter characters after a delimiter in a string

Tags: r

I would like to remove all the letters ([a-z]) that come after a delimiter (e.g. "-"), in a string, e.g:

```
s <- "abc-10abc"
```

So to get:

```
> s2
[1] "abc-10"
```

How can I do this? Thank you

Comment: `gsub("(.*\\d).*", "\\1", s)`

Comment: @Nate That works, thank you. Could you please explain?

Comment: It works here, but does not follow the rule *remove all the letters ([a-z]) that come after a delimiter (e.g. "-")*.  `(.*\\d).*` just says to save everything up to and including a digit and remove everything afterward.  Delimiters are not take into account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
gsub("(.*\\d).*", "\\1", s)
```

The first pattern argument uses `()` to "capture" a group of characters. Inside the capture we are looking for all wild card character until a digit `\\d`. This "captures" everything up until the last digit here.

Since the pattern argument also includes a multiple-wildcard after the capture group, the entire original string is being targeted for replacement. The replace argument `\\1` says to use the first (and in this case only) capture expression from the pattern argument.

Let me know if that's not clear, this is my regex gospel for R regex help https://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/

Like Rich Scriven pointed out you could substitute the `.*` with `[a-z]*` to target just letters a thru z after the last digit. You may want to add the argument `ignore.case = TRUE` to `gsub()` as well incase not everything is lower case:

```
gsub("(.*\\-\\d*)[a-z]*", "\\1", s, ignore.case = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a regex expert but I believe this follows your pattern.

```
gsub("(^.*-[^[:alpha:]]*)[[:alpha:]]*", "\\1", s)
#[1] "abc-10"
```

Explanation:

1. `^` - beginning of string
2. `^.*` any character at the beginning of string followed by zero or more repetitions of it.
3. `-`   matches the delimiter in your question
4. `[^[:alpha:]]*`  the circunflex negates the class `[:alpha:]`, do not match alphabetic characters
5. `(all of above)`  form a pattern group, the first (and only)
6. `[[:alpha:]]*`  match an alphabetic character followed by zero or more repetitions of it

Then in the `replacement` argument `\\1` means to replace the pattern with the first group, so the `[[:alpha:]]*` part is left out.